# Dynamic Gridview - get first child native ads

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, datagridview, uwp

I have a simple dynamic Gridview:

```
<GridView x:Name="MainGridStations" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Stations}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Station">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image x:Name="ImageStation" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"/>
                            <Grid Background="#e4f0fc" Height="65" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="0.8">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="StationName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#2c9a8b" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Now i wanna use native ads with this gridview. In the code for the native ads i need to register the adcontainer that holds the ad for click events and such.
It will always be the first child of the gridview, meaning the first grid container within the gridview.

I've trie this:

```
nativeAd.RegisterAdContainer(MainGridStations.ContainerFromIndex(0));
```

Here it gives me the error, that it can't convert from *Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject* to Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement

Basically it is expecting a direct name of a xaml control which i can't provide. 
How can i overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here it gives me the error, that it can't convert from Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject to Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement

[`RegisterAdContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt809188.aspx) method to register the UI element that acts as a container for the native ad; this is required to properly track ad impressions and clicks.

And available parameter of `RegisterAdContainer` is `FrameworkElement`. But the value of `MainGridStations.ContainerFromIndex(0)` is `DependencyObject`. So it will throw exception.

If you want to display the  Native Ad in the `GridView` first item, you could get the first item when it rendered like the following.

You need to inherit `GridView` and override `MeasureOverride`, `ArrangeOverride` method to get the item, then get child with **Visual Helper**.

```
class MyGridView : GridView
{
    private const string ImageStation = "ImageStation";
    private const string StationName = "StationName";
    private const string RootLayout = "RootLayout";
    private bool isFirst;

    NativeAdsManagerV2 myNativeAdsManager = null;
    string myAppId = "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab";
    string myAdUnitId = "test";

    public MyGridView()
    {
        myNativeAdsManager = new NativeAdsManagerV2(myAppId, myAdUnitId);
        myNativeAdsManager.AdReady += MyNativeAd_AdReady;
        myNativeAdsManager.ErrorOccurred += MyNativeAdsManager_ErrorOccurred;
        myNativeAdsManager.RequestAd();
    }

    private void MyNativeAdsManager_ErrorOccurred(object sender, NativeAdErrorEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void MyNativeAd_AdReady(object sender, NativeAdReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        NativeAdV2 nativeAd = e.NativeAd;
        AdTitle.Text = nativeAd.Title;
        Adimage.Source = nativeAd.AdIcon.Source;
        nativeAd.RegisterAdContainer(AdContainer);
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        if (this.IndexFromContainer(element) == 0)
        {
            isFirst = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isFirst = false;
        }

        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }


    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);

    }
    private Image Adimage;
    private TextBlock AdTitle;
    private Grid AdContainer;

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (isFirst)
        {
            var item = this.ContainerFromIndex(0);
            AdContainer = MyFindGridViewChildByName(item, RootLayout) as Grid;
            Adimage = MyFindGridViewChildByName(item, ImageStation) as Image;
            AdTitle = MyFindGridViewChildByName(item, StationName) as TextBlock;
            isFirst = false;

        }

        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }

    public static DependencyObject MyFindGridViewChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
            if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
                return MyChild;

            var FindResult = MyFindGridViewChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
            if (FindResult != null)
                return FindResult;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the ad-click work for you? I can display it but click doesn't get registered.

Comment: It works in my side. please modify grid name to another name, avoid using `Root`.

Comment: mhh. actually it's not working anymore. i can't inherit from : GridView in my mainclass because it inherits from page. so i have the code in a complete separate class that i'm calling with  var callnative = new NativeAds(); getting nullpointer exception on the AdTitle and others.

Comment: You could get the `GridView` item in the GridView `Loaded` event and then use View Tree Helper to get the chind.